# Finding inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\alpha=\int_{0}^{\pi}\dfrac{x}{5+3\cos x}dx$ and $\beta=\dfrac{16\pi}{\pi^{2}}$, which of the following is definitely true?

(A) $1\leq \beta \leq 4$

(B) $0\leq \beta \leq 2$

(C) $2\leq \beta \leq 5$

(D) $1\leq \beta \leq 3$

Comment: No $\alpha$ in the options !

Comment: I am taking $\cos x=\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{Z})$ but got nothing!

Comment: Surely something is missing in this question.

Answer (score 1):

None are true! $\beta$ is approximately 5.09

Comment: Are you just taking $\pi=3.14$?

Comment: well, a much better approximation but yes.